# Replacement for Sourcery CodeBench for Verifone DTK

Tags: codesourcery

Now that Sourcery CodeBench is no longer open source and is owned by Siemens, is there any alternative to build projects that were earlier built on Sourcery CodeBench for Verifne DTK ? Currently the Sourcery CodeBench for Verifone DTK requires a license and I looking for alternatives such as open souce compilers/toolchains which can used with Eclipse or any other IDE to perform the same task.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The Sourcery CodeBench license status has not changed, and the Siemens rebrand is irrelevant (although the website update is broken temporarily). I think Verifone stopped distributing their version of the tools.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to compile the code without using Sourcery CodeBench ? Like using any other open source tool chain e.g Arm Cross GCC? Just wanted to avoid the dependancy on the license.

Answer (score 0):

I was release manager for SCB for VF, I believe some old gcc will work, but without licensed DTK tools you won't be able to sign application for deploy. If you provide more details what you want to achieve I probably could say something more concrete.
And +1 to ams Siemens acquisition is irrelevant to SCB licensing.